# Passing asteriks in Command Line In Java

Tags: java, command-line

According to some textbooks and resources, using asteriks sign for command line argument is a mistake because when entering it, all files in that directory are listed. The reason for this is that asteriks sign is used for wildcard import.

However, I do not face this problem and I use this code.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Command line : javac Main.java (for compiling)

Command Line : java Main "*" (for running)

Is not facing this problem relevant to operating system which I use ?

Output : *

Comment: Do you expect display list of files?

Comment: It depends what _program_ you pass the `*` into. Different programs handle command line arguments differently.

Comment: Note that it depend on OS too. On Windows, wildcard is parsed by the process. On UNIX, it is parsed by shell.

Comment: In bash, `*` will be converted to a load of filenames before Java ever sees it.

Comment: @khelwood but only if not escaped or quoted (as OP is doing)

Comment: @gktg1414 this actually is not related to Java. it is the command line interpreter that does that *magic*

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger So he is.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a Java question, it's a shell question.

In most UNIX and Linux shells, you can demonstrate what happens using something like `echo`.

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ echo *
*
$ touch foo bar
$ echo *
foo bar
$ echo "*"
*
```

So,

- If there are no files in the directory, `*` ends up as `*`.
- If there are files in the directory, `*` is expanded to their filenames.
- If you put quotes around `*` - `"*"` - that expansion does not happen

What you need to understand is *when* that expansion happens. In typical Linux/UNIX shells (bash, ksh, csh etc.), [various kinds of expansion are done before any command is invoked](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), and that includes filename expansion.

So when `echo` printed `foo bar`, it did not even see `*`. It had already been expanded to the array of strings `char *args[] = {"foo", "bar"}` by the time `bash` invoked the command using the system call `execve("/bin/echo", args)`.

Not all computer systems work like this. For example in MS-DOS, the command shell does no filename expansion at all. So when `DIR *` shows you a list of filenames, it is `DIR.exe` expanding the `*`, not `CMD.exe`.

---

What all this means is that if you write your own program to understand `*` as a command line parameter, you're creating potential confusion for the user. If they forget to put quotes around the `*` then it will behave one way when the current directory is empty, and another way when there are files.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the asterisk in quotes is an indicator to the command line interpreter that the wildcard should not be expanded

Answer (score 0):

That's because your program doesn't list the files that correspond to the input. Your program simply echoes the input as-is.